# how to print hours minutes and seconds from a DataTime object?

Tags: php, datetime

I have this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
try{
  $datetime1 = new DateTime("now");
  $datetime2 = new DateTime("tomorrow");
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  echo  $interval->format(HERE);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Can someone tell me how can i print the hours, minutes and seconds have passed? (in format()` function)

thanks

Comment: Have a look at the doc for date() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php - so what you need is `$interval->format("H:i:s");`

Comment: A pity the four letters "RTFM" are too short to respond as a comment

Answer (score 1):

```
echo  $interval->format("%H:%i:%s");
```

Output will be like this,

```
05:7:19
```

`date()` functions format doesn't need `%` character. But `DateInterval::format` needs it. Also `DateInterval::format` has fewer format characters.
See [DateInterval::format](http://php.net/dateinterval.format) function.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime::format() uses the same formatting as [date()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), so in your example it would be '%H %i %s'.

Comment: `date()` function doesn't use `%`.